# php serve mp4 instantly (before loading everything)

Tags: php, http-headers, html5-video

I'm implementing a HTML5 video player that serves mp4-files.

When I use a regular mp4 file as a source, the video starts pretty soon and I can also seek to parts that aren't downloaded yet.

Now, I want to secure my video files, i.e. they are stored below the web root and the video src is a php-file, that checks, if the user is allowed to view the video.

So my HTML looks like this:

```
...
<video src="http://videoserver.com/stream.php?file=videoxy.mp4">
...
```

And the stream.php:

```
...
if ($access_granted) {
  if ($fd = fopen($path, "rb")) {
    $fsize = filesize($path);
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header("Content-Length: $fsize");
    fpassthru($fd);
  } else {
    die('file not found');
  }
} else {
  die('forbidden');
}
...
```

Now, the video will still be played, but only **after** the video is completely downloaded.

How can I make the video start before everything is downloaded? Also I'd like seeking to not yet downloaded parts to work as before.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/codler/3906826) to be working:

```
...
if ($access_granted) {
  if ($fp = fopen($path, "rb")) {
    $size = filesize($path); 
    $length = $size;
    $start = 0;  
    $end = $size - 1; 
    header('Content-type: video/mp4');
    header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
      $c_start = $start;
      $c_end = $end;
      list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
      if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
      }
      if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
      } else {
        $range = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
      }
      $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
      if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
      }
      $start = $c_start;
      $end = $c_end;
      $length = $end - $start + 1;
      fseek($fp, $start);
      header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    }
    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
    header("Content-Length: ".$length);
    $buffer = 1024 * 8;
    while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {
      if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
      }
      set_time_limit(0);
      echo fread($fp, $buffer);
      flush();
    }
    fclose($fp);
    exit();
  } else {
    die('file not found');
  }
} else {
  die('forbidden');
}
...
```